# Makefile: shell function in lazy variable is not lazy

Tags: makefile

Consider the following Makefile.

```make
$(shell touch /tmp/example.txt)
FILE := /tmp/example.txt
CONTENTS = $(shell cat $(FILE); bash -c 'echo [debugging id: $$RANDOM]')

.PHONY: all
all:
    @cat $(FILE)
    @echo '$$(CONTENTS):' $(CONTENTS)
    bash -c 'echo file-contents-$$RANDOM' > $(FILE)
    @cat $(FILE)
    @echo '$$(CONTENTS):' $(CONTENTS) # This line outputs the old contents. Why?
```

It prints the contents of the file, overwrites with new contents and prints the contents again. It shows as (after second shots of `make`):

```bash
file-contents-1543
$(CONTENTS): file-contents-1543 [debugging id: 15172]
bash -c 'echo file-contents-$RANDOM' > /tmp/example.txt
file-contents-22441
$(CONTENTS): file-contents-1543 [debugging id: 151]
```

The old content is `file-contents-1543` and new content is `file-contents-22441` (the numbers are random), but the last line `echo $(CONTENTS)` does not print the new contents.
I think the command is actually called twice as debugging ids show but shell function in the lazy variable seems to be executed before writing the new contents to the file.

I expect that lazy variable in Makefile is evaluated every time it is referred, the `echo $(CONTENTS)` command always prints the latest file contents. What am I wrong?

By the way, I found that using `CONTENTS = $$(cat $(FILE))` works as I expect. I will using this instead of shell function but is it ok?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I expect that lazy variable in Makefile is evaluated every time it is referred, the echo $(CONTENTS) command always prints the latest file contents. What am I wrong?

First of all, in make's slang these variables are called **recursive**, not lazy. And, yes, they get **expanded** (i.e. recursively substituted) each time they are referred with `$(CONTENTS)`. Considering that `$(eval...)` and `$(shell...)` (as pretty much anything looking as `$(...)`) also went through the same (recursive) expansion procedure (albeit, with some "side-effects"), each expansion of such variable could also result in some sort of "evaluation" or "execution".

Next, the order of expansion in make is a bit specific. In particular, the recipes (i.e. the lines starting with [tab]) are expanded *after* the whole makefile was (pre-)processed, but *before* the first line of the recipe gets executed by shell. Which is the main source of your confusion, I suppose.

> I found that using CONTENTS = $$(cat $(FILE)) works as I expect

`$$` is a way to get a single literal `$` after an expansion procedure. So `$$(cat $(FILE))` when expanded becomes `$(cat /tmp/example.txt)` which is a legal syntax for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) in bash. This means it will work only as part of a bash command (recipe line). If that is what you want then it's okay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it solves my question. The expansions are processed before the commands in the recipe, that makes sense. I also did another experiment as https://ideone.com/JMuNRU and the date in the text file was the oldest date.